# Not sure how to pass .env file to Dataproc Job Submit call

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataproc, .env, python-dotenv

I created a python library that in certain places must reach out to an API call to fetch some data. The way I handled credentials is by creating a .env file at the root of our repo and we used `dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv.find_dotenv())` to read that information.

I am planning on running this code through a Dataproc cluster that's already created by submitting the job like so:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark gs://tabsearch/main.py \
 --cluster=tabsearch-cluster \
 --region=us-central1 \
 --py-files=gs://tabsearch_poc/src.zip
 --properties-file=gs://tabsearch_poc/.env
```

Where `gs://tabsearch/main.py` is the main file, and `gs://tabsearch_poc/src.zip` are its supporting files, and `gs://tabsearch_poc/.env` the file with credentials. When I execute the call above, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/dskajdnaksjdw28834e2/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    inventory_toolkit = toolkit()
  File "src.zip/src/inventory_tool/toolkit.py", line 14, in toolkit
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 300, in find_dotenv
    for dirname in _walk_to_root(path):
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dotenv/main.py", line 257, in _walk_to_root
    raise IOError('Starting path not found')
```

How is this typically done? It's worth mentioning that we're trying to avoid passing credentials in the `gcloud` command because eventually it will be handed over to other services to call the system im building.